# How to compare two different List of list?

Tags: java

Example of list:

```
    List1 =[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9,10]]
    List2 =[[11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19],[20]]
```

I have two lists of list and want to compare list element in below fashion

```
    1=>11, 2=>12,3=>No element present in List2
    4=>13, 5->14,15->No element present in List1,16->No element present in List1
```

but the condition is List 2 can contain more element than list1. How i can compare two lists with each other?

I have checked online solutions and tried to iterate through for loop as well but none of them are fulfilled my requirement.

1. Size of list1 and list2 are equal and I have already added a check to start comparison only if size is equal.

I can iterate through both the lists with the help of for loop but struggling with the comparison.

```
for (int m = 0; m < List1 .size(); m++) {

            for (int n = 0; n < List1 .get(m).size(); n++) {


                System.out.println("List1" + m + "==>" + List1 .get(m).get(n));

            }

            System.out.println("========================================================");
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < List2.size(); i++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < List2.get(i).size(); k++) {
                System.out.println("========================================================");
                System.out.println("List2" + i + "==>" + List2.get(i).get(k));
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your requirement? What do you want out of comparison? Also, I guess you meant `2=>12` instead of `2=>22`

Comment: are the size of list1 and list2 equal as well?

Comment: Iterating with two loops should work, i guess (that's basically the plainest solution).

Comment: You need to be more clear about your requirements. Is [1] < [1,2]  ? Is [2] > [1,2] ? etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Is it list of booleans, where `i`-th element means whether there is such `j` that `List1[i][j] == List2[i][j]`? Show output for your example.

Comment: I already explained how i want my comparison   1=>11, 2=>12,3=>No element present in List2
    4=>13, 5->14,15->No element present in List1,16->No element present in List1

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isEqualsDeeply(List<List<Integer>> one, List<List<Integer>> two) {
    one = one != null ? one : Collections.emptyList();
    two = two != null ? two : Collections.emptyList();

    if (one.size() != two.size())
        return false;

    Iterator<List<Integer>> it1 = one.iterator();
    Iterator<List<Integer>> it2 = two.iterator();

    while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
        List<Integer> subOne = it1.next();
        List<Integer> subTwo = it2.next();

        subOne = subOne != null ? subOne : Collections.emptyList();
        subTwo = subTwo != null ? subTwo : Collections.emptyList();

        if (subOne.size() != subTwo.size() || !subOne.equals(subTwo))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**P.S.**

It seems that for `Integer` standard `equals` works fine as well:

```
public static boolean isEqualsDeeply(List<List<Integer>> one, List<List<Integer>> two) {
    one = one != null ? one : Collections.emptyList();
    two = two != null ? two : Collections.emptyList();
    return one.equals(two);
}
```

Comment: Getting error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Comment: Add parameter `<T>` instead of `Integer`

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>

Comment: Could you provide your `main` class? Test examples with this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.max(int n, int m)` to compare the list sizes and get the longest one for your nested for loop. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> list1 = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(1,2,3),
            Arrays.asList(4,5),
            Arrays.asList(6,7),
            Arrays.asList(8,9,10));
    List<List<Integer>> list2 = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(11,12),
            Arrays.asList(13,14,15,16),
            Arrays.asList(17,18,19),
            Arrays.asList(20));

    for(int i = 0; i <list2.size();i++){
        int j = Math.max(list1.get(i).size(),list2.get(i).size());
        for(int k = 0; k<j; k++){
            System.out.print(k<list1.get(i).size()?list1.get(i).get(k) +" => ":"No element present in List1 => ");
            System.out.print(k<list2.get(i).size()?list2.get(i).get(k) :"No element present in List2");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("===============================");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have madec couple of chanes and now got result as expected. thank you  so much

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you're stuck on the java aspect of checking whether a list has another element remaining, of if you're stuck on the logic. If its the logic, here's some javascript code that gets the job done :

```
var list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9,10]];
var list2 = [[11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19],[20],[21]];

function compareLists(l1,l2){
    var i = 0;
    var maxLength = Math.max(list1.length,list2.length);
    for(i = 0; i< maxLength; i++){
        var sl1 = list1[i], sl2 = list2[i];
        compareSublists(sl1,sl2);
    }
}

function compareSublists(sl1,sl2){
    if(sl1 === undefined){
        console.log(sl2 + " has no corresponding sublist in list 1");
    }else if(sl2 === undefined){
        console.log(sl1 + " has no corresponding sublist in lis 2");
    }else{
        var i = 0;
        var maxLength = Math.max(sl1.length,sl2.length);
        for(i=0; i<maxLength;i++){
            var sl1e = sl1[i], sl2e = sl2[i];
            if(sl1e === undefined){
                console.log(sl2e+" has no element in list 1");
            }else if(sl2e === undefined){
                console.log(sl1e+" has no element in list 2");
            }else{
                console.log(sl1e + " => " + sl2e);
            }
        }
    }
}
compareLists(list1,list2);
```

Converting to java should not be too much of an issue; however I haven't touched java in years, so I can't help you out there, apologies.